# How to solve a Session Hijacking in my firebase app which uses aws amplify and congnito for auth sessions?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, firebase-security, aws-amplify

Currently I have my App deployed on Firebase and using AWS Amplify with AWS Cognito for authenticate users and Sessions

The security Team reported that is a Session HIjacking vulnerability.

```
# Used Cookie

[
    {
        "domain": "my_domain.firebaseapp.com",
        "expirationDate": 1654892898,
        "hostOnly": true,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "name": "IdToken",
        "path": "/",
        "sameSite": null,
        "secure": false,
        "session": false,
        "storeId": null,
        "value": "XXXXXXX"
    }
]


# LocalStorage

{
    "CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.MY_ID_CLIENT_APP.LastAuthUser": "MY_SAML_PROVIDER",
    "CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.MY_ID_CLIENT_APP.MY_SAML_PROVIDER.accessToken": "XXXXX",
    "amplify-redirected-from-hosted-ui": "true",
    "CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.MY_ID_CLIENT_APP.MY_SAML_PROVIDER.idToken": "XXXXX",
    "amplify-signin-with-hostedUI": "true",
    "CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.MY_ID_CLIENT_APP.MY_SAML_PROVIDER.clockDrift": "0",
    "CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.MY_ID_CLIENT_APP.MY_SAML_PROVIDER.refreshToken": "XXXXX"
}
```

My code uses:

```
    //Verify Session

    useEffect(() => {
        const paths = queryString.parse(window.location.search)
        if (!state.NotLogin) {
            if (paths.code && paths.state) {
                setloadHosted(true)
            }
            Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(res=> {
                let finalUser = ""
                let usernameCognito = res.username.split("_")

                if (usernameCognito.length === 2) {
                    finalUser = usernameCognito[1]
                }
                else {
                    finalUser = usernameCognito
                }

                sweetAlert(`Welcome, ${finalUser}`, "success")
                Cookies.set('IdToken', res.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken, { expires: 1 })
                actions({ type: "setState", payload: { ...state, username: finalUser } })
                setloadHosted(false)
                setShowOption(true)
            })
        }
        else{
            setShowOption(true)
        }
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

In principle, detecting session hijacking can be done by:

1. Tying a session to an IP address
2. Using rotating refresh tokens

The (1) method, requires you to store the IP address of the sign in / up request in the created JWT / session token. On each subsequent request, you would check that the IP in the token is the same as the IP of the request. If not, you can return a 401. Whilst this method adds an extra layer of protection, it can result in false negatives / positives (For example, what if the user starts to use a VPN).

Method (2) is more robust, but much more complex to implement. In a nutshell, you need to change the refresh token on each use (Not sure if cognito has that), and if a previous refresh token is used after a new one is already issued, then it's a session theft. This has almost no false positives or negatives, assuming that the implementation is done correctly. Going into the implementation details in this answer would be difficult, so I am linking a blog: https://supertokens.com/blog/the-best-way-to-securely-manage-user-sessions

Finally, you can decrease the surface area of the attack vector:

- Use httpOnly cookies to store session tokens which will prevent token theft via XSS
- Enable rotation of JWT signing keys (not sure if Cognito has that, but if they do, enable it).
- Keep a short lifetime for the access token and a long lifetime for the refresh token. This way, in case the access token is compromised, then the risk is limited. If the refresh token is compromised, then session theft detection can kick in (assuming that you are using rotating refresh tokens)
- Be sure to protect against CSRF attacks.
- If you are storing session tokens yourself, be sure to store only their hashed version in the db. This limits their exploit in case the db is compromised.

If Cognito doesn't have some of these features, consider using a different solution for session management. In this case, you can consume the ID token sent by Cognito to create a new cookie based session for your app, and ideally this session should have all the security features.

Hope this helps!